# Zurb Foundation Joyride not showing up at all

Tags: html, zurb-joyride

I was trying to use Foundation Joyride on a project of mine, and I couldn't get it to show up at all.

Does anyone know what I might be missing? I got to the point where I made a separate html and just stripped it to find out if someone else was conflicting with it, the console also shows nothing.

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-icons.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="home-screen">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="headerDiv" class="large-12 columns large-text-center">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="panel">
            <h3 id="subtitle">Subtitle </h3>
            <a id="startButton" class="medium success button radius">Start!</a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- At the bottom of your page but inside of the body tag -->
  <ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
      <li data-id="headerDiv" data-text="Next" data-options="tip_location: top">
          <p>Hello and welcome to the Joyride documentation page.</p>
      </li>
      <li data-id="subtitle" data-class="custom so-awesome" data-text="Next">
          <h4>Stop #1</h4>
          <p>You can control all the details for you tour stop. Any valid HTML will work inside of Joyride.</p>
      </li>
      <li data-id="startButton" data-button="Next" data-options="tip_location:top;tip_animation:fade">
          <h4>Stop #2</h4>
          <p>Get the details right by styling Joyride with a custom stylesheet!</p>
      </li>
      <li data-button="End">
          <h4>Stop #3</h4>
          <p>It works as a modal too!</p>
      </li>
  </ol>

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**PS:** I did try to place the `<ol>` under all of the script tags, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the javascript call to start joyride

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with this too, change your last lines of code to this

```
<script>
    $(#joyride-list).foundation('foundation', 'start');
</script>
```

or if you are using the joyride in multiple pages, put this in your layout.

```
  <script>
    $(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question ! But if it is good to give a solution, it would be better to explain why the OP version did not work and why yours works.

Comment: By the op version , you mean?

Comment: OP means Original Post. It is a common abreviation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I get it, and by that OP you are referring to the Zurb-Foundation's original post, or your origin post? Either way , I can not see what to explain, I just posted what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the 'start' mentioned by the others above worked for me aswell.

Later on I wanted to start joyride via a button. In that case you need to load foundation,
and after that you need to create a function to 'start' joyride. So my code looks something like below, where 'activateJoyride' is the function to start joyride obviously:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).foundation();

    function activateJoyride() {
        $(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
    }
</script>
```